# how can I create additional loopback interface permanentely?

Tags: rhel, networkmanager, loopback

I can use `ip addr add 130.100.0.5/32 dev lo` to create a loopback interface.

However, if I use `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-lo` to config it, it doesn't show up:

```
DEVICE=lo
IPADDR=130.100.0.5
NETMASK=255.255.255.255
ONBOOT=yes
NAME=myloopback:1
```

Comment: What version of RHEL are you using?

Comment: I am using RHEL 8.x. It looks like in the 9.x networkmanager can do it already. But 8.x seems impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### For RHEL X, where 8 <= X < 9.1

This is addressed explicitly in [a knowledgebase article](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2108251):

> NetworkManager traditionally did not manage the loopback interface by design.
>
> Red Hat customer Requests For Enhancement resulted in upstream work to add it, which was done in NetworkManager 1.41.6 with:
>
> - [Support loopback interface (v2)](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/-/merge_requests/1332)
>
> This is a large feature and was deemed too risky to backport to RHEL 8's earlier NetworkManager code.

The same article suggests [creating a systemd unit](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/6844771) to manage the configuration of the loopback interface. For example, for what you're doing, something like this would work:

```
[Unit]
Description=Manage Loopback service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
User=root
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c '/usr/sbin/ip addr add 130.100.0.5/24 dev lo'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

- Place the service in e.g. `/etc/systemd/system/configure-loopback.service`
- Enable it by running `systemctl enable configure-loopback.service`
- Reboot

You should end up with:

```
[root@localhost ~]# ip addr show lo
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 130.100.0.5/24 scope global lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

---

On a RHEL 7 system, if I edit `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-lo` so that it looks like this:

```
DEVICE=lo
IPADDR=127.0.0.1
NETMASK=255.0.0.0
NETWORK=127.0.0.0
IPADDR1=130.100.0.5
NETMASK1=255.255.255.0
# If you're having problems with gated making 127.0.0.0/8 a martian,
# you can change this to something else (255.255.255.255, for example)
BROADCAST=127.255.255.255
ONBOOT=yes
NAME=loopback
```

Then when the system reboots, `lo` looks like:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 130.100.0.5/24 brd 130.100.0.255 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

That seems to accomplish what you want.